# AFNetworking errors

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, afnetworking, xcode7

Since I have updated Xcode6 to Xcode7 my project has this three errors. Does anybody know why? And do you have a solution?

[image: Xcode7]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if u have installed pods for project then delete it and install new pods...

Comment: @ParthPatel Thank you!